# firebase order by not working as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geohashing

the order by does not work as expected in my query. I´m trying to find users in the given radius and to sort the users by membership and lastBoostAt but the order by query is doing nothing. do someone has a solution? the order array has the 3 orders [currentlocation.hash, membership, lastBoostAt]. The problem is that the documents in my result are not sorted by the given orders.

here is how i tried to solve it:

```
    this.queryFilter = [];
return this.userCollectionService.getUsersByDistance(this.user.currentLocation,
  20000, this.queryFilter, [
    {key: 'currentLocation.hash', descending: 'asc'},
    {key: 'membership', descending: 'desc'},
    {key: 'lastBoostAt', descending: 'desc'}
  ]).then((users) => {
    this.standardUsers = users;
})
```

```
    const center: any = [currentLocation.lat, currentLocation.lng];
    const bounds = geohashQueryBounds(center, distance * 1000);
    const promises = [];
    let queryFilters = [];
    let queryOrders = [];

    if (filters) {

      for (let filter of filters) {
        queryFilters.push(where(filter.key, filter.opr, filter.value))
      }
    }

   if (order) {
      if (typeof(order) === 'object') {
        for (let o of order) {
          console.log(o.key);
          queryOrders.push(orderBy(o.key, o.descending));
        }
      } else {
        queryOrders.push(orderBy(order, 'desc'));
      }
    }

    let i = 0;

    for (const b of bounds) {
      console.log(b);
      if (i === 0) {
        queryFilters.push(where('currentLocation.hash', '>=', b[0]));
        queryFilters.push(where('currentLocation.hash', '<=', b[1]));
      } else {
        queryFilters.push(or(...[where('currentLocation.hash', '>=', b[0]), where('currentLocation.hash', '>=', b[1])]));
      }

      i++;
    }

    console.log(queryOrders);
    const q = query(
      collection(this.db, 'Users'),
      ...queryFilters,
      ...queryOrders,
      //orderBy('currentLocation.hash'),
      order);

    promises.push(getDocs(q));

    const snapshots = await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log(snapshots.length)

    const users: IUser[] = [];
    for (const snap of snapshots) {
      for (const doc of snap.docs) {
        const lat = doc.get('currentLocation.lat');
        const lng = doc.get('currentLocation.lng');

        const distanceInKm = distanceBetween([lat, lng], center);
        const distanceInM = distanceInKm * 1000;
        if (distanceInM <= distance * 1000) {
          users.push(doc.data());
        } else {
          console.log(true);
        }
      }
    }

    return users;
```

when i dont use the geohash filter then it works fine but i need a max distance in my query. i appreciate it if someone has a better solution to solve the problem.

here ist the result
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm9mi.jpg)

that should be sort by membership and lastBoostAt. lastBoostAt is just a timestamp in the database and the membership is a number in the database. 3 = vip, 2 = gold, 1 = standard. As u can see it is not sorted by hash or membership.

[raw result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkZI0.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "the order by query is doing nothing"? Are you saying it yields no documents, or are you saying that it generates an error of some sort?  Please edit the question to be clear what it's doing, and how that is different than what you expect.  Also we can't see the contents of your database or the variables in your code, so we have no idea what this code is actually going to do in practice.  You might want to provide more information so that we can see what's happening.

Comment: @DougStevenson hey, i updated my question and i hope it is now more clear

Comment: We still can't see the data in your database that would be used in the query, nor can we see the raw query results.  That screenshot doesn't  really help at all.

Comment: @DougStevenson i added a picture with the raw result

Comment: It's not clear to me that your query actually specifies an ordering on the fields you're expecting. Everything is hidden behind variables whose contents we can't see.

Comment: I'm with Doug here, it's hard for us to see what query you're actually firing. I recommend stepping through your code line by line in a debugger, and checking if it is indeed adding all the clauses that you expect it to add. --- If it turns out that indeed it adds all the clauses, try to reproduce the problem with simpler code: just a single query, with values hard-coded, and then log the results. That sort of [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) gives you the best chance that someone here can help.

Comment: @DougStevenson is it now better for u to understand?